# Is it possible to have the same section repeated in the same template?

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to have the same section repeated in the same template? If so, how?
template:

```
{% section 'two_images' %}
{% section 'two_images' %}
```

two_images:

```
<section data-aos="fade">
  <div class="flex-images">
    <img src="{{ section.settings.img1 | img_url: "3979x943" }}">
    <img src="{{ section.settings.img2 | img_url: "3990x943" }}">
  </div>
</section>

{% schema %}
  {
      "name": "Two Images",
      "settings": [
      {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "img1",
          "label": "First Image",
          "info": "Recommended sizes: 3979x943"
      },
      {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "img2",
          "label": "Second Image",
          "info": "Recommended sizes: 3990x943"
      }]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

The sections are showing but same pictures for both. I'm guessing it has to do something with "id"? Since it's repeated twice. What's the work around?

Answer (score 0):

Right, so you cannot simply duplicate sections and expect them to have different content. Sections contains unique settings for each one of them, so you would need to create another section in `"/sections"` folder, lets say `"two_images_2"`, and put same content there. Then you can include it in your template.

If the html content for both sections is exactly the same, you can create snippet with this html and include it in both sections, to avoid duplicating same html over and over again. Please note this does not applies to `{% schema %}`, as content of this tag is required in sections, so this will need to be duplicated

Hope this answer will clarify the logic behind sections for you,

Thanks